# How to Pick up Link(URL) using a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to pick up the link(URL) of a web page using **Google Chrome Extension**.The problem with the picking up the link is that HTML page can implement what i want but the Extension is not implementing the same code. I mean that the same code works for HTML web page but does not work for **Google Chrome Extension** although both are coded in HTML page but there might be some restrictions that might be there which is preventing me to implement the code.

This is my HTML page.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h1> 
            LinkLet
        </h1>
        Email the Link <input type="text" name="myinputbox" class="form1"          id="myinputbox"><br>
    </form> 
</body>
```

This is my JS page to pick link.This page is working while run independently on the browser but does not work when bundled with Chrome Extension.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
var newURL = "Link.html";
chrome.tabs.create({url: newURL});
});
var url = document.URL;
var elem = document.getElementById("myinputbox");
elem.value = url;
```

And my Manifest file is

```
{
"background" :{
"scripts" : ["background.js"]
},
"manifest_version" :2,
"name": "My Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Opens up a local webpage",
"icons": { "1": "1.png" },

"browser_action": {
"default_title": "Hi123",
"default_icon": "1.png"
},
"permissions": [
"tabs"
]
}
```

Comment: Where is your manifest file? `var url = document.URL;` will never fetch needed URL if it is in any other page than content scripts

Comment: i tried the tab.url method also but it is not working either.i want to pick up the URL of the page on which i am currently before pressing the extension button/icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to pick up the URL of the page on which you are currently before pressing the extension button/icon.

Use the following code.

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    "active": true,//fetch active tabs
    "currentWindow": true,//fetch tabs in current window
    "status": "complete",//fetch completely loaded windows
    "windowType": "normal"//fetch normal windows
}, function (tabs) {
    for (tab in tabs) {
        console.log(tabs[tab].url);// Use this URL as needed
    }
});
```

it can eliminate above effort.

**P.S:** `var elem = document.getElementById("myinputbox");` the above code will never work in background page because of missing element.

Comment: is var a = console.log(tabs[tab].url); correct.i wanted to store the link in a variable and display on a web page that opens when i click on the icon.

Comment: @KshitijMarwah `var _somename = tabs[tab].url;` is the correct syntax if you are looking for storage of url.

Comment: Sir then how can i store the current tab url after the code you have been writing as how can console.log be saved?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail as to how to store the URL.I tried your code but its not getting me the desired results.

Comment: @KshitijMarwah: your java script code will never work, because you are doing a DOM query from a page where an element do not exist.

Comment: But i was trying out your code only and not other one. so can you please correct me on this topic.